# AngularJS/Rails Paperclip file upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, file-upload, paperclip

I trying to implement a file upload with AngularJS/Rails using the Paperclip gem.
I fix the file input problem with a directive.
Now i want to send the image with the other data of the post but the image datas are not send.

HTML :

```
<form name="PostForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="post.title">
  <input type="file" file-upload />
  <textarea ng-model="post.content"></textarea>
</form>
```

My controller :

```
$scope.create = function() {

    function success(response) {
        console.log("Success", response)
        $location.path("posts");
    }

    function failure(response) {
        console.log("Failure", response);
    }

    if ($routeParams.id)
        Post.update($scope.post, success, failure);
    else
        Post.create($scope.post, success, failure);
    }

$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.post.image = args.file;
    });
```

My model :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at

  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

But when i send it to the server side, the request is like that :

```
{
  "content":"Hey",
  "created_at":"2013-08-31T17:54:32Z",
  "id":17,
  "image_content_type":null,
  "image_file_name":null,
  "image_file_size":null,
  "image_updated_at":null,
  "title":"Image",
  "updated_at":"2013-08-31T17:54:32Z",
  "user_id":4
}
```

So, no data conserning the image are send to the server, any tips on how to do that ?

Comment: Hey Joe, this might helpful https://gist.github.com/vajapravin/48059fd9d64bb42f012f513cebd391ea

Answer (score 0):

I progress now, i succeed to send file data via form-data content-type, the problem is now in the rails controller, an error is launched :

```
undefined method `stingify_keys`
```

Here is the code i use to send the data :

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': false },
        transformRequest: function (data) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("post", angular.toJson(data.post));
            formData.append("image", data.image);
            return (formData);
        },
        data: { post: $scope.post, image: $scope.image}
    }).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("success!");
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("failed!");
});
```

And that's the data which are send to rails :

```
-----------------------------2122519893511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post" {"title":"sdsdsd","content":"sdsd"}
-----------------------------2122519893511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="dad.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg [image-data]
-----------------------------2122519893511--
```

Comment: hi @jeo-bow, are you able to to upload image using paperclip in angualarjs with rails?